# How to get svn log from remote repository without checking files out

Tags: svn

I have over 100 repos and want to retrieve their full log without checking these repos into my computer.

I know svn log is producing the log file but how can I pass url, username, pass as args?

Comment: If you don't have the Subversion Book at hand, just try `svn help log`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to checkout a working copy to view the revision log.

The command that you look for is [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html). Here is an example:

`svn log https://svn.example.com/repos/MyRepository/MyProject/trunk`

Read the documentation: [SVNBook | Examining History](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.history.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
 svn log -l 1 svn+ssh://<repo_address>/trunk
```

that can be different from your local repo ./trunk

you can encapsulate it in a bash script within a "for loop" of each repo reading from a file

```
while read repo
do
  svn log -l  1 "$repo"
done < list_of_repo.txt
```